# How can I hide an Application from the Updates Tab in the Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, mac, mac-appstore, software-update

I had an app on my MacBook that I never used. I recently did a clean install of Mountain Lion on the same MacBook (not using the Migration Assistant or anything to copy my old data). I reinstalled the apps that I wanted from the App Store (and obviously didn't install the ones I used to have that I no longer wanted).

Now the App Store shows one of my old apps in the updates tab, even though I have never touched that app since my reinstall. There is only one app doing this, there are other apps that I didn't end up installing that I used to have, but they don't appear as updates like this one.

I have tried everything to get rid of the app from the updates. I have even succumbed to the frustration and clicked update, which installed the app, then I deleted it from my computer, and then the app reappeared in the updates immediately.

Any help on how I can get this app to leave me alone forever would be appreciated. Is there a way I can hide an app from the updates tab?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Purchases** in the **Mac App Store**, locate the Application you want to hide, *right-click* on it and choose *Hide Purchase*.

After a clicking the *Hide Purchase* button in the prompted screen, the item will fade and you no longer will receive update notifications of that Application.

To unhide it just go to **Mac App Store / Store / View My Account**, then click on **View Hidden Purchases** from the *Account Information Page*, and click the *Unhide* button.

In both cases you'll need to be logged in.

Comment: I already have it hidden, hoping that this would be the case but the update is still visible, even though it is hidden in purchases...

Comment: In addition to hiding the purchase, you need to remove the application. Drag it from the Applications to the trash.